# Oracle: Add incremental ids for unique combination of two other columns

Tags: sql, oracle, escaping

I have a table which looks like this

```
Seq ID | Uid | Type | URL
```

for each `Uid` I can have multiple `Urls` for any given type, for example

`Uid 123` can have `5 video urls` and `6 image type urls`

I want to insert auto incrementing seq id for each combination of `Uid` and `Type` so in the previous example the seq `id` of `uid 123` and type video will go `1,2,3,4,5` for each `video url` and `1,2,3,4,5,6` for each `image type url`, and same for all the other `uid` and `type` combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would refrain from trying to store this kind of artificial construct in the database. If needed, it can be generated at query time:

```
SELECT Uid, Type, URL,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Uid, Type ORDER BY URL) AS SeqID
    FROM YourTable
```

Comment: can I specify a specific type so that it gives back the SeqId only for Type Video and for any other Type leave the Seq Column as it is?It should still return all the types only put seq id for a specific one) since some have existing seq ids

Comment: one more question: why do we need to do order by URL

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do this in a query?

```
select row_number() over (partition by uid, type order by url) as seqID, . . .
from table
```

You can also do this in an update, for an after-the-fact update:

```
with toupdate as (
     select row_number() over (partition by uid, type order by url) as newseqID, . . .
     from table
)
update toudpate
    set seqID as newseqID
```

If you want to do it as part of an insert, you'll need to create a trigger to maintain the column values.